# Android Holo loading spinner in CSS

Tags: css

I need to know how can I make the Android Holo loading spinner in CSS without images. I've tried, but I don't know how can I do it. This is what I need (animated, like in Android):

[image: Holo spinner]

How can I do it in CSS without images?

Comment: How you can make an image using css? seems impossible. It has to be an GIF image..

Comment: I cannot make an image with CSS, but it's not "really" impossible, you can use base64 for show a picture without have a picture, just with CSS or HTML to show it, but what I need right now, it's make the Android Holo spinner (the one like the picture but animated) with CSS without using images

Comment: The base64 thing is referring to SVG i think which is made for Graphics not a CSS which is made for styling not designing images. But it may be possible however. Nothing is impossible.

Comment: How did this question ever survive this long? It's terribly over-broad and OP shows absolutely no effort to solve the problem on his own.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I can't seem to do it without images either.

I managed to make a true replication of the Holo spinner [as defined in AOSP](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable/progress_medium_holo.xml) with just two images for the [outer](http://yuku-android-util.googlecode.com/git-history/148f949b61febb228e564f36af3a8956814a090c/ActionBarSherlock4/res/drawable-xhdpi/abs__spinner_48_outer_holo.png) and [inner](http://yuku-android-util.googlecode.com/git-history/148f949b61febb228e564f36af3a8956814a090c/ActionBarSherlock4/res/drawable-xhdpi/abs__spinner_48_inner_holo.png) gradients. [Here's a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/MattiasBuelens/T2XAx/)

The problem is that those two images have a "polar" gradient: they start from one color at 0° which gradually blends into a second color when going around the circle. There's a sharp color change at 0° where the two colors meet. I don't know if there's any way to create such gradient in CSS using just `linear-gradient`s or `radial-gradient`s.

**UPDATE** I got working with no images, yay! [Check out the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/MattiasBuelens/pTvmW/)

I approximated each polar gradient using two halves of a linear gradient. Some disadvantages of this approach:

- The color fading is not perfect. Colors fade along the vertical axis instead of along the angle.
- There's a small glitch where the two halves meet up at the bottom, as they give slightly different colors to points on the same horizontal line. This becomes more noticeable as the stroke width of the spinner increases.

For small spinners - which is the usual use case - it works just fine and it looks great!

Comment: Updated my answer, now actually without images! :-)

Comment: Nice, +1 for the no images solution.

Comment: @MattiasBuelens Awarding you the bounty, you deserve it :)

Comment: @Mr.Alien Thanks, appreciate it! Now go and put this spinner to good use. :-)

Comment: @MattiasBuelens I won't be using it for now, but innovators should be gifted something for what they achieve so awarded you ;)

Comment: Hi, i'm using your image based spinner since i think it looks smoother (both are very cool though and I have already +1'd your answer) and i have noticed that the image based CSS is missing the webkit-keyframes property so the animation doesn't work on Chrome. I have copy/pasted it from your css only example and it worked, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29842771/holo-spinner-example-with-images-doesnt-work-while-pure-css-does/30072398#30072398

Comment: @valepu Good catch, I didn't really test that one in Chrome. I've updated the fiddle for future reference. Thanks!

Comment: @MattiasBuelens You are welcome, glad I helped (2 years later, but still :) )

Answer (score 11):

### Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/7cGc3/4/

I can get the spinning effect with pure CSS. More advanced effects are possible (see below), but the limiting factor is that this technique relies on a rectangular clipping region.

[image]

<sub>You should see this (animated, of course) in Chrome, IE10, FF. IE9 looks correct but won't animate. Safari needs a [slightly modified](http://jsfiddle.net/WNphF/1/) version.</sub>

Sandbox for more elaborate effects (webkit only, more similar to accepted answer): http://jsfiddle.net/7cGc3/5/

---

### Code

<sub>*Vendor prefixes omitted for brevity.*</sub>

**HTML**

The HTML is extremely simple.

```
<div class="spinner"></div>
```

**CSS**

The important pieces here are border-radius, [clipping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/clip), and animation.

```
.spinner{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 54px;
    border: 4px solid #999;
    position: relative;
}

.spinner:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -4px;
    left: -4px;
    border: 4px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 54px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    clip: rect(0px, 60px, 50px, 0px);

    animation: rotate 2s;  
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes rotate {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

Comment: F*** Awesome :D I have already upvoted you but will award you a bounty too :)

Comment: Thanks. Your animation code was helpful...the trick was figuring out a way to do it with borders only (no images).

Comment: That's pretty close, but it's not the "real" Holo spinner. Have a look at [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MattiasBuelens/T2XAx/), you'll see it's a more complex animation. Unfortunately, I don't know how one could make that without images though.

Comment: @TimMedora Thank you, and I was not able to figure out the arc thingy

Comment: @MattiasBuelens - my actual fiddles have the appropriate vendor prefixes; I fixed Safari by modifying the markup a little (just updated my answer). I'll take a look at replicating your animation with CSS only.

Comment: @TimMedora I seem to have missed your comment about omitting prefixes for brevity, my bad.

Comment: @TimMedora I managed to get it work without images, check [my updated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16250775/1321716).

Comment: @TimMedora I'll be awarding this to mattias so don't mind ;) because he made a better one than our's

Comment: No worries, his actually works as intended and I learned a few things in the process.