# Holo spinner example with images doesn't work while pure CSS does

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-animations

Related to this question: [Android Holo loading spinner in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16250260/android-holo-loading-spinner-in-css) I have noticed that the accepted answer's first example, the one with images, doesn't work on chrome (i just see a static grey ring) while it works on Firefox and IE 11.

Even though the purpose of the question was to make a spinner without images and both are very nice I find the first one slightly better looking (on firefox, that is) and i'd like to use it but I don't know why it doesn't work on chrome and I want to know if there's a fix, both for future references (so i know what to avoid and/or how to fix it) and to know if I must stick to the one without images

My Chrome version is 42.0.2311.90 (32-bit)

Comment: I just look at the jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/MattiasBuelens/pTvmW/) and it just works fine. I do not know why it is not working for you. 

My chrome version is: 42.0.2311.90 (64-bit).

I know there is a problem with animating css with Google Chrome if you look here:
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/w4YlFvEMQNw

I think it depends on your operating systems.

Comment: That's the working jsfiddle (pure CSS), try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/MattiasBuelens/T2XAx/ I have checked all the examples that were reported as not working in the discussion you linked and they all worked for me. I'm running Windows 7 64 bit, ATI video card (saw in the discussion someone who said it might've been caused by Nvidia drivers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since i assumed both spinners were correct i didn't realize it was missing the webkit-keyframes property. Today i watched once again the css and noticed by chance that the css spinner had it while the image-based spinner didn't. Adding this to the image based spinner css worked

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotate-outer {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(1080deg);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate-inner {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(720deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
}
```